# Load Object from MongoDB with JPA (hibernate)

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, jpa, object-persistence

I created an `@Entity` and stored it in a MongoDB via Hibernate using the Java Peristence API (JPA) to be able to switch to another JPA implementation (like DataNucleus, EclipseLink etc.), but now I cannot load it in anymore. I get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.addUninitializedEntity(Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/EntityKey;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hibernate/persister/entity/EntityPersister;Lorg/hibernate/LockMode;ZLorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;)V
    at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.loadFromResultSet(OgmLoader.java:1143)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.instanceNotYetLoaded(OgmLoader.java:1065)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.getRow(OgmLoader.java:959)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.getRowFromResultSet(OgmLoader.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.doQuery(OgmLoader.java:373)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(OgmLoader.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.loadEntity(OgmLoader.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.load(OgmLoader.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.load(OgmLoader.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.entity.impl.DynamicBatchingEntityLoaderBuilder$DynamicBatchingEntityLoader.load(DynamicBatchingEntityLoaderBuilder.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4002)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1142)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2600(SessionImpl.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2762)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2741)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:978)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionDelegatorBaseImpl.get(SessionDelegatorBaseImpl.java:629)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1075)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1033)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.impl.OgmEntityManager.find(OgmEntityManager.java:97)
```

All classes are something similar to this or using a subset of it:

```
// package and imports (lombok and jpa)

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Bla {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private <T extends Object> attribute;

    @OneToMany
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<<T extends Object>> list;

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name="TASKS", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user"))
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Map<<T extends Object>, Boolean> doneTask;

}
```

And I am using `entityManager.find(Class<T> type, Object o)` to load the Objects. Is there anything I may have been doing wrong?

Comment: JPA does not define support for non-RDBMS datastores, and all providers that also allow persistence to MongoDB likely will store relations differently, hence you will (likely) have no portability due to that fact. Better to look at what each provider wants to store the relations as and decide based on that. As for your problem, use the LOG. Also, you cannot have a `@OneToMany` to an `Object` ... has to be an entity

Comment: @NeilStockton, Object is just generic selected, like my classes are not called Bla, they are all entities. Thank you for your hint, but it is not a solution.

Comment: As for your error message, well NoSuchMethodError says simply the libraries you have in the CLASSPATH are inconsistent ... compiled with one thing and run with another.

Comment: @NeilStockton, if you didn't know it already, I am an idiot, if you misspell your dependencies in your build.gradle, you'll not get all hibernate stuff you need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using a MongoDB you need

```
runtime "org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:$versions.mongodb"
```

and your ogm/persitence framework, in my case Hibernate, with your framework/db connection:

```
compile "org.hibernate.ogm:hibernate-ogm-core:$hibernate_version"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:$hibernate_version"
runtime "org.hibernate.ogm:hibernate-ogm-mongodb:$hibernate_version"
```

and your persitence api (jpa, jdo or proprietary), in my case JPA with hibernate/jpa implementation:

```
compile "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final"
compile "$versions.persistence_api"
```